# Passing multiple values to a SQL query IN statement in PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I've figured out how to run SQL queries with PowerShell and turn them into arrays I can work with. I've also figured out how to pass specific subsets of variables or arrays to the query. Like this:

```
$LastMonth = [DateTime]::Now#.AddMonths((-1))
# define target database and server
$TargetServer = 'server name'
$TargetDatabase = 'db name'

$ConnectionString = "Server=" + $TargetServer + ";Database=" + $TargetDatabase + ";Trusted_Connection=$true;";
$TargetConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString);
$TargetConnection.Open();

$sql = "SELECT [AVAILABILITY_SAID_ID]
    ,[AVAILABILITY_MINUTES]
    FROM [dbo].[AVAILABILITY_MINUTES]
    where [AVAILABILITY_MONTH] = $($LastMonth.Month) and [AVAILABILITY_YEAR] = $($LastMonth.Year);"
# execute SQL command
$TargetCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql, $TargetConnection);
$reader = $TargetCommand.ExecuteReader()
    $availability = @()
    while ($reader.Read())
    {
        $row = @{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
        {
            $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
        }
        $availability += new-object psobject -property $row            
    }
    $reader.Close()
```

What I can't figure out is how to do it as an IN statement with multiple items. I can get the list to be passed, but I can't figure out how to get the parentheses around it so that the query actually works.

```
$TargetServer = 'server name'
$TargetDatabase = 'db name'

$ConnectionString = "Server=" + $TargetServer + ";Database=" + $TargetDatabase + ";Trusted_Connection=$true;";
$TargetConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString);
$TargetConnection.Open();

          $sql = "SELECT
            incidentid AS EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE,
            Priority AS Priority_Code,
            keycode AS ASSET_KEY,
            Description AS EVENT_DATA,
            CreatedDateTime AS [Opened],
            ClosedDateTime AS [Closed]
            FROM incident
            WHERE keycode IN $("'" + ($said.Saidkeycode -join "','") + "'")
            AND Priority IN (1, 2)
            AND CONVERT (date, CreatedDateTime) <= DATEADD(DAY, -2, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
            AND CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
            ORDER BY EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE";
          $SourceCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlCmd, $SourceConnection);
          $reader = $SourceCommand.ExecuteReader()
          $incidents = @()
          while ($reader.Read())
          {
              $row = @{}
              for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
              {
                  $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
              }
              $incidents += new-object psobject -property $row            
          }
$reader.Close()
```

From what I've found, parametrisation is the answer, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to get it to actually work.
I'm not sure if this is broken or if I just can't figure out how to get the results out of the dataset.

```
$TargetServer = 'server name'
$TargetDatabase = 'db name'

$ConnectionString = "Server=" + $TargetServer + ";Database=" + $TargetDatabase + ";Trusted_Connection=$true;";
$TargetConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString);
$TargetConnection.Open();
        $sqlCmd = $SourceConnection.CreateCommand()
        $sqlCmd.Connection = $SourceConnection
          $sql = "SELECT
            incidentid AS EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE,
            Priority AS Priority_Code,
            keycode AS ASSET_KEY,
            Description AS EVENT_DATA,
            CreatedDateTime AS [Opened],
            ClosedDateTime AS [Closed]
            FROM Cherwell.dbo.Incident
            WHERE keycode IN (@SAID)
            AND Priority IN (1, 2)
            AND CONVERT (date, CreatedDateTime) <= DATEADD(DAY, -2, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
            AND CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
            ORDER BY EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE";
          $sqlCmd.CommandText = $sql
          $sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@SAID", [Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar, 4).Value = $("'" + ($said.Saidkeycode -join "','") + "'")
          $sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
          $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
          $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

Comment: Passing a *scalar* variable is just that, A *scalar* value. `IN ('a,b,c,d')` would be the same as `= 'a,b,c,d'` *not* `IN ('a','b','c','d')`. You would either need to use a table type parameter, or *split* the value in your SQL. I will,. however, note that it's unliekly your delimited values will fit in a `varchar(4)`.

Comment: @Larnu I get a syntax error if the values do not have () around them.
I'm using varchar(4) as that is the value of the column of the SQL table. Should I be using something else. They are all 4 letters long.

Comment: If you have a *delimited* value, how to you propose that more than one 4 character value fits in the `varchar(4)`? `'abcd,wxyz'` as a `varchar(4)` is `'abcd'`.

Comment: I need my IN statement to be ('abcd', 'ewoh', 'avpe', 'awep'). So each item that it is searching for would be a varchar(4), correct?

Comment: As I stated, `@SAID` is a **scalar** variable; it *cannot* contain tuples; *"You would either need to use a table type parameter, or split the value in your SQL."*.

Comment: Could you point me to something that explains what on earth that means? I seem to be missing the prerequisite knowledge required to understand what you and some of the documentation are talking about.

Comment: What *what* means?

Comment: What "@SAID is a scalar variable; it cannot contain tuples; "You would either need to use a table type parameter, or split the value in your SQL."" means.

Comment: So do you not know what a scalar value is?

Comment: @Larnu not entirely. I've looked up a couple of things on it, but I'm not understanding how or why it matters if it's scalar. Once the string of text is in place and passed to SQL, why does it care what the variable originally was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do this, but it's what I finally was able to get to work. I defined the properly punctuated array as a new variable `$insaid`, and used that new variable with the parentheses in the IN statement.

```
$TargetServer = 'server name'
$TargetDatabase = 'db name'

$ConnectionString = "Server=" + $TargetServer + ";Database=" + $TargetDatabase + ";Trusted_Connection=$true;";
$TargetConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString);
$TargetConnection.Open();
$insaid = $("'" + ($said.Saidkeycode -join "','") + "'")
          $sql = "SELECT
            incidentid AS EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE,
            Priority AS Priority_Code,
            keycode AS ASSET_KEY,
            Description AS EVENT_DATA,
            CreatedDateTime AS [Opened],
            ClosedDateTime AS [Closed]
            FROM incident
            WHERE keycode IN ($insaid)
            AND Priority IN (1, 2)
            AND CONVERT (date, CreatedDateTime) <= DATEADD(DAY, -2, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
            AND CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
            ORDER BY EVENT_LIFECYCLE_VALUE";
          $SourceCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlCmd, $SourceConnection);
          $reader = $SourceCommand.ExecuteReader()
          $incidents = @()
          while ($reader.Read())
          {
              $row = @{}
              for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
              {
                  $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
              }
              $incidents += new-object psobject -property $row            
          }
$reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options open to you here. I am going to take the code I used in your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72527984/how-do-i-pass-an-variable-array-member-to-a-sql-query-in-powershell), as I still had it open in my IDE.

For a delimited list, this would be simply splitting the value in your SQL. I *assume* you are on a (fully) supported version of SQL Server, as you make no mention that you aren't. This means you can simply use `STRING_SPLIT`:

```bash
$connectionString = 'Server="srvsql2019dev\Sandbox";Database=Sandbox;Trusted_Connection=true;'

$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
try{
    $sqlConn.Open()
    $sqlCmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
    $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn
    $query = "SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Databases,','));" #IN using STRING_SPLIT
    $databases = Get-Content -Path "./DBNames.txt" #txt file containing database names.
    $sqlCmd.CommandText = $query
    $sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Databases", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar,4000).Value = $databases -join "," # Pass the values as a comma delimited list. 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
}
finally{
    if ($sqlAdapter -ne $null) { $sqlAdapter.Dispose(); }
    if ($sqlConn -ne $null) { $sqlConn.Close(); }
}

$dataSet.Tables
```

Note that I define the parameter as *4000* characters long, not 4, or some other very short value; as this would result in truncation.

The alternative method, as I mentioned, is to use a table type parameter (TTP). To do this, you will first need to create the `TYPE`, and you would also need to create a stored procedure. As you are using an inline query here, then I won't cover this here. If, however, you are passing 100's of values in your `IN`, then moving to a TTP (with an `INDEX`) will likely be more performant.

Another method is with json. Json is easy to create in PS (`ConvertTo-Json`) and consume in a SQL query (`OPENJSON`). Json might be overkill for a simple delimited list but is easier than a TVP for multiple columns since one doesn't need to create a type.

Comment: Adding another method is with json. Json is easy to create in PS (`ConvertTo-Json`) and consume in a SQL query (`OPENJSON`). Json might be overkill for a simple delimited list but is easier than a TVP for multiple columns since one doesn't need to create a type.

Comment: Good point, @DanGuzman . Would be worth posting your own answer, in my opinion.

Comment: It will be between 50 and 75 four letter strings. I guess we're making progress. I now get this error ```Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a Object[] to a String." (Line[266] Code[    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)])``` I'm assuming that is the data being returned from the query?